# Zener voltage clamping

Tags: voltage-regulator

I would like to understand how a zener diode clamps the voltage.
[image]

I1 = I2 + I3, in order to calculate I2 I need the zener's resistance which is not doable since it is not a resistor. However I don't need to make such a calculation because I can just assume that Vd of zener is 5.1V and therefore Vd across R2 is going to be 5.1V, so order to calculate current in this circuit O would just use Vt = 500I + 5.1 which is I = (Vt-5.1)/500

My question is: Why do I need to assume that voltage drop of a resistor in parallel to zener diode will be equal to a drop of zener itself?

Comment: It's called a Zener diode with one n...

Comment: "Why do i need to assume that voltage drop of a resistor in paralel to zenner diode will be equal to a drop of zenner it self." - They are in parallel, so by definition they have the same voltage drop on them

Comment: @WesleyLee can u please send me a link to the definition of such a rule

Comment: @AntonStafeyev It's basic electronics: Elements that are parallel to each other have the same voltage across them, elements that are in series have the same current through them

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Parallel_circuits - first sentence

Comment: @WesleyLee and it is comforms to highest voltage drop ? for example another component will drop more voltage then the zener

Comment: Think about it this way:  When things are in parallel their two ends are connected directly together, so of course they are always at the same potential (how could they be different?).  Now you need to think about what the current must do for this to be the case.

Comment: @evildemonic i probably phrased my question like an idiot :) but i found an answer, if smth provides less of a potential loss, then zener will not conduct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to solve the question **manually**, you need to do iterative calculations:

- You start with assuming the zener isn't there, calculate the voltage drop across R2.
- If the voltage drop across R2 is smaller than the **rated** clamp voltage (5.1V in your case) of the zener diode, you can stop and neglect the current through the (leakage) zener diode
- If the voltage drop across R2 is about or larger than the rated clamp voltage of the zener diode, check the **datasheet** of the zener diode and hope there is a graph that shows the relation of clamping voltage to current.
  It is easiest to (first) neglect the current through R2 i.e. assume R2 to be open.
  Start with the rated clamping voltage (5.1V), calculate the current through R3 (Vcc-5.1V)/R3, check the voltage-current graph, adjust the zener clamp voltage and iteratively find the correct clamping voltage and corresponding current.
  Then, calculate the current through R2 using the clamp voltage found in previous step. If this current is negligible compared to the current through R3, you can stop. If not, you should recalculate the whole thing involving the current through R2, using the zener's voltage-current graph, but you're likely not way off the clamping voltage you found earlier.

If you want to solve the question **easy**, you just simulate it with LTSpice or a comparable tool and have it solved in no time.

Comment: Best approach for extra credit: solve **manually** first, then **simulate** in a simulator and **confirm** that your manual calculation was correct :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Not only to learn/know what you're doing, you'd better do it manually, also, when \$V_{R2} << V_{z, rated}\$ or \$I_{R1} >> I_{R2}\$ using a simulator is a waste of time.