# Comparator with hysteresis calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the hysteresis of the comparator using currents but something isn't right. I'd like a little help to find the hysteresis thresholds without the simplified equations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw9hCa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage at inverting input is:

\$ V_{(-)} = \dfrac{V_{IN}}{2} = 0V ...6V \$

The reference voltage is:

\$ V_{REF} = 8.2V \$

So, **when the output of the Op-Amp is low** we have a voltage divider as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZHwj.png)</sup>

Then the current \$I_{1}\$ will be \$\dfrac{V_{REF}}{R_{4} + R_{5}} = 0.112 mA\$

So the upper threshold is \$ V_{th(H)} = 0.112mA * 72kΩ = 8.064V\$

**When the output of the Op-Amp is high** we have the following circuit. That I think is analyzed with the Superposition Theorem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMrAnW.png)</sup>

And the lower threshold is \$ V_{th(L)} = 8.252V\$. Is this correct?

Would it be different if it was a non-inverting comparator?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. Which means that you need Vin > 2 * 8.2V (due to voltage divider at the inverting input) to be able to see the circuit at work

Comment: Although the Zener diode will clamp at 8.2V in your case, you cannot **simply assume** \$V_{ref} = 8.2 V\$. Check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478471/zener-voltage-clamping/478473#478473

Comment: @G36 would it be different if it was non-inverting comparator?

Comment: @DKNguyen I mean, Input at Vref point (variable input voltage) and a stable reference voltage at V(-)

Comment: @MrBit Define what you mean by non-inverting comparator because from what I see, that doesn't hold any meaning. Comparators don't invert, and work on positive feedback and the hysteresis also needs positive feedback. That means no matter what you do, the hysteresis feedback loop must always go from the output to the non-inverting input.

Comment: Yes, it changes it because if you swap the input signals then the equivalent circuits will be different since the hysteresis resistor must always sit between the output and the non-inverting input.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was talking about this schematic: https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Comparator-Hysteresis-Calculator.phtml It looks like the Vp is stable and the input feeds the non inverting input. Positive feedback still exists on the circuit.

Comment: @MrBit The levels of of the hysteresis changes

Comment: @DKNguyen How do I calculate those levels?

Comment: @the same way you have here for the most part